# If my company can buy a copy of Virtual Machine on the Mac, which should I buy?

Tags: virtualbox, vmware, parallels

I think VirtualBox might be too troublesome and slow to use.  My company is willing to buy a copy of Virtual machine for me I think, is VM Ware, Parallels, or other products (for Mac) the best in your opinion?

(also it has to work with the .vhd on http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=21eabb90-958f-4b64-b5f1-73d0a413c8ef&displaylang=en  so IE 7 and 8 can be installed (to test our websites))

Comment: What will you be using it for?

Comment: oh mainly for testing our websites on IE 7 and 8

Comment: Hm, I've never known VirtualBox to be slow, nor do I find it troublesome at all. I'm assuming you've actually tried it and found it to be lacking in some way, rather than simply balking because of its pricetag ($0.00)?

Comment: @Kromey sometimes, VirtualBox says "Non Optimal Settings detected" without giving any single detail.  Sometimes, the virtual machine fails to start because I pulled out the USB flash drive when there was one when I sleep the machine previously, but I am in the office and the USB flash drive is at home.  Sometimes it says the whole .vhd is invalid, and some people needed to tell me to do some command line to make it work again.  Now, the latest VirtualBox will not run Microsoft's free VPC VHD.  I guess VirtualBox changed the hardware config without caring whether it works with those VHD or not.

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer VMware, solely out of personal preference, parallels is just too much.

Comment: just too much as in "too bulky" and eat up too much memory?

Comment: I would say it's got some unnecessary things, Vmware's also compatible with Windows and Linux Vmware Workstation if you want to move as well

Answer (score 0):

VMware is a superior product to all forms of workstation side virtual machine editing. After you make a machine in Virtual box you'll hate it the moment you want to make a duplicate of the machine, it won't let you! You have to use their silly command line interface to change some id or something. With VMware you just copy to another folder. VMware has support for more OS'es, can hide everything to a task bar icon (windows, I don't know about mac), and is much faster suspending to disk.